I have two formulations of quadrotor dynamics, one in euler angle velocities, and one in body frame angular velocities. I am unable to see equivalence
In the following MIT lecture notes
Equation (6.10) is on the following form
\begin{equation}\begin{bmatrix}
m \dot{v}^w \\
J \dot{\omega}^B
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-mge_3 \\
-\omega^B \times J \omega^B
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
R^w_B & 0 \\
0 & I_3
\end{bmatrix}
\text{Fw}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot{p}^w = v^w
\end{equation}
In this Matlab tutorial, the quadrotor dynamics are given like this:
$$\ddot{p}^w=\ddot{\xi} = -(0,0,g)^T + R(0,0,T)^T/m.$$
$$\ddot{\eta} = J^{-1}(\tau_B - C(\eta,\dot{\eta})\dot{\eta}).$$
$$J = W_{\eta}^T I W_{\eta},$$
With $W_{\eta}$ being the transform between angular euler velocities ($\dot{\eta}$) and angular body frame velocities $^B$.
% Transformation matrix for angular velocities from inertial frame
% to body frame
W = [ 1,  0,        -sin(theta);
      0,  cos(phi),  cos(theta)*sin(phi);
      0, -sin(phi),  cos(theta)*cos(phi) ];

Notable is the fact that lecture notes use $J$ as inertia, whereas MATLAB uses $I$ as inertia and $J$ as the Jacobian that is used to express the rotational energy in the inertial frame. Also, the thrust+torque vector relation between the two are $\begin{bmatrix}{0\\0\\T\\\tau_B}\end{bmatrix}=\text{Fw}$
I have tried pretty hard, using cross product identities etc., to show the equivalence between the two, but I have so far been unable to. I would appreciate any help greatly.
